# Excel Lookup Username

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010.  I have the below two functions in a module to retrieve the current user login name and full name:

```
Function GetUserFullName() As String
    Set WSHnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    UserName = WSHnet.UserName
    UserDomain = WSHnet.UserDomain
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & UserDomain & "/" & UserName & ",user")
    GetUserFullName = objUser.FullName
End Function

Function ADUserName()
    ADUserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function
```

On my worksheet I call them by using the below in two different cells:

```
=ADUsername()

=GetUserFullName()
```

Works fine and retrieves my details.  As soon as someone else on their PC opens it, its still showing my details - why is this?  I cannot get it to refresh.

Comment: Is this a case for Option Explicit at the top of the code ?

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html

Comment: have you verified that the users have macros enabled? You say you update cells with them. But if their settings prevent macros from executing, then the two cells you update can never update, they keep their previous values, which are your informations. So first step: validate they can run macros. if they can, then make sure your code is actually called... if it is, then I don'T know...

Comment: The reason I'm telling you that is I've seen this many times. User machines often have macros disabled by default for security reasons. Make sure your users are bright enough before you enable them, as viruses can easily go through excel macros. I've seen this before. Buyers are generally the people that bring in viruses that way. They receive fake quotes by email, open the excel file even tho it's OBVIOUSLY fishy, and boom, as soon as the file is opened, the macro launches, and there you go, the whole network is infected!

Comment: Got Option Explicit and also tried the Application.Volatile line, but still not updating.  User also has macros enabled.

Comment: it's working now, it was the Option Explicit - for some reason it didn't complain about this on my computer but did on the end users PC.  Anyway, thanks to everyone.